# JavaScript date string sorting behaves differently on IE & Chrome

Tags: javascript, sorting

Below JavaScript line are executed differently on Chrome and IE.

```
var months =  ["Apr-2016", "Jun-2016", "Feb-2016", "Jan-2016",  "Mar-2016",  "May-2016", "Feb-2016", "Jun-2016", "Feb-2016", "Feb-2016", "Jan-2016"] ;
var uniqueMonths = months.filter( function (value, index, self) { return self.indexOf(value) === index;} );
uniqueMonths.sort(function(a,b){ return ((new Date(a).getTime()) - (new Date(b).getTime()));  });
```

On IE I get

```
uniqueMonths = ["Apr-2016", "Jun-2016", "Feb-2016", "Jan-2016", "Mar-2016", "May-2016"]
```

On chrome I get

```
uniqueMonths =  ["Jan-2016", "Feb-2016", "Mar-2016", "Apr-2016", "May-2016", "Jun-2016"] ;
```

What is reason for this beahaviour ?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: `Apr-2016` These are not valid date literals,.. Some browsers might attempt at decoding it, some might not like you have seen.. :)  In fact IE returns `"Invalid Date"` for these

Answer (score 2):

The date literals you have provided are invalid. It seems that Chrome parses it nevertheless. In this regard Firefox follows suit with IE, as it says:

```
new Date("Apr-2016")
```

> Invalid Date

It is always preferable to use ISO dates, or if you don't, I'd recommend using a library, which provides a way to initialize JavaScript Date with specified format strings. Unfortunately native JavaScript lack this feature.

Comment: Can recommend me a lightweight library for this.

Comment: I use `moment.js` extensively, I can recommend it.